# Python Twitter Unicode Error 'UCS-2'

Tags: python, unicode, bmp

Hello when I try to get some tweets with nltk or tweepy. I get an error like that

```
>>> from nltk.twitter import Twitter
>>> tw = Twitter()
>>> tw.tweets(keywords='love', limit=50)
```

Tweet outputs

```
RT @BookOProverbs: Love your neighbor as yourself. -Mat 22:37
    RT @davebernstein: Dear @SpeakerRyan &amp; @GOP:

You had 8 years– 8 years to come up with a replacement to #ACA.
```

ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    tw.tweets(keywords='love', limit=50)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\nltk\twitter\twitterclient.py", line 380, in tweets
    self.streamer.filter(track=keywords, follow=follow, lang=lang)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\nltk\twitter\twitterclient.py", line 118, in filter
    self.statuses.filter(track=track, follow=follow, lang=lang)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\twython\streaming\types.py", line 66, in filter
    self.streamer._request(url, 'POST', params=params)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\twython\streaming\api.py", line 154, in _request
    if self.on_success(data):  # pragma: no cover

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\nltk\twitter\twitterclient.py", line 73, in on_success
    self.handler.handle(data)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\nltk\twitter\twitterclient.py", line 404, in handle
    print(text)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 29-29: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk
```

Comment: What OS and Python version are you using where `print()` is trying to use `UCS-2`?

Comment: I use Windows and Python 3.6. I think it's an emoji error.

Comment: I'm sure it is, but the question is why 'UCS-2' is being used for console encoding? I would expect 'utf-16', which should work. Perhaps it's a bug in Python, I know console I/O changed drastically for Windows in 3.6. If you could determine which character is being printed you could really make a minimal example.